# problem with routing in asp.net mvc3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a page under the default /Home/Index. On this page I have a link to log out the user:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "LogOut", new { controller="Users" })
```

When I click on this link, debugger goes to default controller, that means Home and action Index. 
This is my routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
         "LogOut", // Route name
         "Users/LogOut", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Users", action = "LogOut" }
         );

routes.MapRoute(
         "Default", // Route name
         "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
         );
```

What is wrong here? Why it isn't going to the appropriate controller and action?

[EDIT]
From js code I can log out the user using

```
$.post('/Users/LogOut',function(){
window.location.replace("/Home/Index");
});
```

My LogOut action is simple

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            string login = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;    
            usersService.RemoveLogin(login);
            usersService.RemoveUsersMessages(login);    
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("LogIn", "Users");
        }
```

but the problem is not with this method. When I click on the link I'm going streight to the default default /Home/Index. Don't know why from client code it works, but using link to send postback to server not.

Comment: Looks like both routes are the same.

Comment: So can you show me how to fix it? I have problem to see, where the problem is.

Comment: What else routes do you have?

Comment: That's all. Only these two. But I have found something. If I clean the cache in browser and log to my app, then when I click on this link, I'm going to the LogOut action. But if I log myself from this vbrowser once again and click the link, debugger goes to the /Home/Index. That situation I have on IE, Opera and Firefox. Only in Chrome no matter how many times I log in, link works ok. This is strange situation which I can't understand.

Comment: It seems to be something is being cached, are you caching anything? Did you check the `FormsAuthentication` in `web.config`?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Omit the first route definition

Because it maps to the same thing as your default route defined after it:

```
controller = Users
action = LogOut
```

So this would still be the same if there was no custom `Users/LogOut` route...

#### 2. Define your ActionLink properly

You don't have to define controller as you did (although it should work just as well).

```
@Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "LogOut", "Users")
```

should do the trick just fine.

#### 3. If this still doesn't do the trick

Then provide the code (edit your question) you have in:

```
public class UsersController
{
    function ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        // what's inside here?
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used workaround for this, but after a month, I still want to know why this isn't working.
Even if I remove the first route from my prevoius post and change the action link according to your suggestion, this doesn't work. 
What is strange is that, from js or using a form on the page I can send request to this address and it work like the link should. I will update my previous post with my code.